# getting text from a textview to display in a string in android

Tags: android, string, textview

I am trying to create a Share button that once the user presses will allow the user to share to a social networking site.

I have a textview with the text "Chipotle" in my xml and would like the text "Chipotle" to appear in my String Intent. So for example, if the user was to post it onto Facebook it would display "Hey I'm going to Chipotle" and will allow the user to post this onto their wall.

I have done so far this:

```
placeName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place_text);
placeName.getText().toString();
String eShare = "Hey I'm going to" + placeName;
```

With this I get the following

```
 I'm going to android.widget.TextView{123212432423....app:id/place_text)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign a variable to this line

```
placeName.getText().toString();
```

Like this

```
placeName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place_text);
String placeNameString = placeName.getText().toString();
String eShare = "Hey I'm going to" + placeNameString;
```

Comment: I see what I did wrong there. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not grabbing the text from your textview. It'll work this way:

```
placeName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place_text);
String eShare = "Hey I'm going to " + placeName.getText().toString();
```

Comment: thanks :) this method also works as well as Marko's.

Answer (score 0):

Try using String class as follows

```
placeName=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.place_text);
String str=placeName.getText().toString();
String eShare="Hey! I am going to "+str;
```

This will give the desired result ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.getText().toString()` in your assignment too. If you like it in one row:

```
String eShare = "Hey I'm going to " +
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.place_text)).getText().toString();
```